# select statement inside sp containing value SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, variables, select, stored-procedures

I'm having a simple issue that I believe solution is under my nose, but still cannot figure it out.

I have a stored procedure that expects the user for 2 imputs:

```
@userid int,
@subtotal int
```

My stored procedure also needs a value from a table that can be obtained from the following query:

```
SELECT discountid FROM historical WHERE userid = @userid
```

So, I just need to hold the value I obtain from this query (which is an int) into a variable I'll use in my whole stored procedure, so I can call it and use it later.

The problem is I don't know how to declare a variable to hold the value from this query in order to be used later.

I searched and found something like:

```
@userid int,
@subtotal int,
@discountid int = (SELECT discountid from historical where userid = @userid)
```

and...

```
@userid int,
@subtotal int,
SELECT @discountid = discountid from historical
where userid = @userid;
```

...but none of them seems to work. I'm currently using SQL Server 2008. Hope somebody can help me out a little, sorry for my english as i'm not a native speaker, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to `DECLARE` this variable and then assign to it. Also make sure that your query returns only one row if not you will get an error as soon as you can't assign N rows to one INT variable. So to prevent this I've added `TOP 1` to the select statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YOUR NAME
@userid int,
@subtotal int

AS

Declare @discountid int;
SELECT TOP 1 @discountid = discountid from historicalwhere userid = @userid;
.....
```

Comment: yes!!! I believe this is what I was looking for. I was declaring my variable in the first part of the sp, thus making the user to insert his own value of this variable, which is something I don't want. I had to include it after the 'AS', that was my error. Let me recheck if everything is working fine, and I'll come back here a little later. Thanks!